# Sqlalchemy select issue with related table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have model 'User' who belongs to model 'Role'. One 'Role' has many 'User' and one 'User' has one 'Role'.

If I want to select all users where 'Role' is hidden lets say (this is purely an example) I must do something like this:

```
User.query.join(Role).filter(roles_table.c.hidden==1).all()
```

Just by using join in this query i get the following message:

> Select statement 'SELECT role.hidden FROM role, user WHERE role.id =
>   user.role_id' returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation;
>   specify correlate() to control correlation manually.

Can anyone point me to the right direction of having this query working?

Answer (score 1):

What if you try following instead:

```
User.query.join(Role).filter(Role.hidden==1).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Having `User` class has a relationship to `Role`, the simplest way would be:

```
User.query.filter(User.role.has(hidden=1))
```